# ionic 2: How can I get console messages from android device

Tags: android, adb, ionic2

I am deploying debug builds to my android phone via `ionic run android`.

How can I view `console.log` messages?

Comment: This helped me when I was doing game for android on Unity3d: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor - You need install android SDK and JDK - Setting the JAVA_HOME: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html - Maybe you will come across this problem: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1323731/unable-to-list-target-platforms-please-make-sure-t.html - This short video explains how to use it (monitor): https://youtu.be/55rkbsjhA3U

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When you deploy app to your android phone, you can show the error log in google chrome.

Steps by step instructions:

- Connect your device to your computer
- Run adb devices ("C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools") to display name of devices (you may not need this step)
- Run google chrome and type "chrome://inspect/#devices" .
- Choose "inspect" for your app.

Comment: i was trying "adb logcat" But your method is cool.. Thanks Any Way

Comment: for more details check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBXjlIRw4ek