# Ionic App not running on Android Device

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I created my App Completely using my PC browser

when I did an Android Build and deploy on my Device it stays at a blank white screen.

So i decided to host the files in /www to debug.

I get the Error 0 619759 error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined, http://10.12.1.205:8100/build/js/Reflect.js, Line: 894

20029 error Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators, http://10.12.1.205:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js, Line: 36793

**Any Help please**

**Ionic Info**
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v4.4.7

**Device Info**
ADV 4.2.2
Kernel 3.4.5

Comment: your problem is in your js files. You call something like `undefined.6`. Check your code

Comment: It should b noted that the application runs well on a google chrome browser. but any other browser it doesnt

Comment: Please use [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744809/ionic-2-how-can-i-get-console-messages-from-android-device/38757834#38757834) to see error log and find your solutions.

Comment: DOesnt still help me Hoang

Answer (score 0):

Try use

//tsconfig.json

```
target: 'es5'
```